# Remover borda que aparece no navegador Chrome e Firefox

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como remover borda que aparece no navegador Chrome e Firefox. Já no navegador Edge não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.fa-admin {
  font-size: 23px !important;
  line-height: .75em;
  vertical-align: -15%;
  position: absolute;
}

.avisosAdminNum,
.mensagensAdminNum {
  font-size: 12px;
  //font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d11010;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30%;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/785bf17c00.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a tabindex="0" class="btn popover-dismiss avisosAdmin" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" title="Avisos">
      <i class="fa fa-bell fa-admin btn-preto "></i>
      <div class="avisosAdminNum ">99</div>
</a>

<a tabindex="0 " class="btn popover-dismiss mensagensAdmin "data-placement="bottom " data-toggle="popover " data-html="true " data-trigger="focus " title="Mensagens">
      <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-admin btn-preto"></i>
      <div class="mensagensAdminNum">99</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar [`bottom`](http://cssreference.io/property/bottom/) e [`right`](http://cssreference.io/property/right/) do CSS?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Obrigado, resolvido.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Consegui, mas tenho outra dúvida, veja se pode me ajudar.

Comment: Vc não deveria fazer isso, principalmente por uma questão de Acessibilidade... http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1):

A classe `.btn` quando tem o `:focus` junto acaba adicionando um `box-shadow` gerando a aparencia de uma borda, você precisa adicionar na sua classe .btn:focus o box-shadow: none !important para dar um overwrite na classe do bootstrap.

```css
<style>
.fa-admin {
  font-size: 23px !important;
  line-height: .75em;
  vertical-align: -15%;
  position: absolute;
}

.avisosAdminNum,
.mensagensAdminNum {
  font-size: 12px;
  //font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d11010;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30%;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 21px;
}

.btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}


</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/785bf17c00.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a tabindex="0" class="btn popover-dismiss avisosAdmin" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" title="Avisos">
      <i class="fa fa-bell fa-admin btn-preto "></i>
      <div class="avisosAdminNum ">99</div>
</a>

<a tabindex="0 " class="btn popover-dismiss mensagensAdmin "data-placement="bottom " data-toggle="popover " data-html="true " data-trigger="focus " title="Mensagens">
      <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-admin btn-preto"></i>
      <div class="mensagensAdminNum">99</div>
</a>
```